# Enable OPcache on PHP Version 5.5.35

Tags: php, caching, opcache

Operating system is Centos 6 w/ Apache 2.15, and PHP was installed using the following repository.

```
[root@devserver drupal-8.1.1]# yum info php55u
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.xmission.com
 * epel: mirror.cpsc.ucalgary.ca
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * ius: mirrors.kernel.org
 * updates: mirror.sesp.northwestern.edu
1704 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Installed Packages
Name        : php55u
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.5.35
Release     : 1.ius.centos6
Size        : 9.0 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : ius
Summary     : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP and Zend and BSD
Description : PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make
            : it easy for developers to write dynamically generated web pages.
            : PHP also offers built-in database integration for several
            : commercial and non-commercial database management systems, so
            : writing a database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The
            : most common use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI
            : scripts.
            :
            : The php package contains the module (often referred to as mod_php)
            : which adds support for the PHP language to Apache HTTP Server.

[root@devserver drupal-8.1.1]#
```

My phpinfo doesn't list OPcache.  It is also not in my php.ini file.

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is available as a separate package - I believe this would be something like php55u-opcache on CentOS - [source](https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/)